# mariadb server not running after install amazon linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mariadb

My mariadb server is not running after I install it with `yum install mariadb-server`.  after running this command, it displays:

mariadb-server-10.2.38-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-server-5.7.35-1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed

Nothing to do

then when I do `rpm -q mariadb-server`, it says its not installed.

is there anything wrong about the installation?

Answer (score 0):

As it it mention in to the message you should install `mysql-community-server`

And you have it already installed

Comment: But it said it is already installed? now when I sudo mysql_secure_installation, this error displays:

Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: @eggplants, you need probably to start it

Comment: I've tried restarting it but no luck. i've followede everything from their documentation. the mysql parts really not working for me. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

Comment: @eggplants, this is another question, please create new one and this question there